# Remove space from xml element name and discard mutiple elements retaining one

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

Input :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <products>
            <product ID="123">
                    <Product Name>Sample Name 1</Product Name>
                    <Images>
                            <Image>url1</Image> 
                            <Image>url2</Image> 
                            <Image>url3</Image> 
                    </Images>
            </product>
            <product ID="456">
                    <Product Name>Sample Name 2</ProductName>
                    <Images>
                            <Image>url4</Image> 
                            <Image>url5</Image> 
                            <Image>url6</Image> 
                    </Images>
            </product>
    </products>
```

Output :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <products>
            <product ID="123">
                    <ProductName>Sample Name 1</ProductName>
                    <Image>url1</Image> 
            </product>
            <product ID="456">
                    <ProductName>Sample Name 2</ProductName>
                    <Image>url4</Image> 
            </product>
    </products>
```

As you can see above there <strike>are two</strike> one change:

<strike>The element tag "Product Name" is changed to "ProductName".</strike>

There are multiple "Image" elements per product nested under "Images" element out of which only the first is retained and others are discarded and is brought up in the hierarchy.

Can one xslt do this?

Also is it possible to not have errors when this xslt transformation is done multiple times on a same file?
Last request, i could not find a suitable title/tag for this request. Please suggest something which will be easier for others to find. I would update it (If allowed).

Comment: As @hr_117 points out, the input isn't valid XML. You therefore shouldn't expect XML tools to be able to work with it (some may, but it's more likely by accident than by design).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Actually following very simple template can do this job.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Images">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Image[1]" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the first part of the question

Comment: Thank you Jirak, it worked. Jim i have addressed the first part through simple file operation in which i have coded to find and replace the bad element names with the good one :)

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because your XML is **not well formed**.
Spaces are not allowed in element name. IF the XML is well formed it would be easily possible to fulfill your request 2.

Assuming you get somehow the well formed XML. Than have a loo for **identity transform** [e.g.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT)

And than add a template for Images which only concider the firs Image:

```
<xsl:template match="Images">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=" @* | Image[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you share something for request 2, assuming request 1 is fulfilled through something else.